# Redirect to Url after domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get redirect by click on button, I use:

```
<inputtype="submit" onclick="location.href='first';" value="goSomewhere1"/>
<inputtype="submit" onclick="location.href='second';" value="goSomewhere2"/>
```

and it workf if is clicked on page `http://ADDRESS` but if is clicked when `url` is like `http://ADDRESS/something` it redirects to `http://ADDRESS/something/first`

How is it possible to get redirect just before `ADDRESS` but not put this value (`ADDRESS`) because it could change? (for this example it should get `http://ADRESS/first` insted of `http://ADDRESS/something/first`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `/first` not `first`.

Without a slash, it's a relative link. With the slash, it's absolute to the base URL.

```
<input type="submit" onclick="location.href='/first'" value="goSomewhere1"/>
<input type="submit" onclick="location.href='/second'" value="goSomewhere2"/>
```

Comment: You also have `inputtype`, but I imagine that's just a typo on SO. There should be a space in there.